# Buffer ownership in Netty 4: How is buffer life-cycle managed?

Tags: netty

I've been trying to write an HTTP client to fetch multiple feeds concurrently (up to 1k), also as an exercise to learn Netty 4.

My question is, if there is a good explanation somewhere how the new ByteBuf infrastructure works? Who "owns" them, how are they shared (are they?) ? Does every ChannelHandler in a ChannelPipeline has it's own ByteBuf?

Here is an example that left me puzzled:

I added an instance of the following class to a HTTP client pipeline:

```
public class MyFilter extends MessageToMessageDecoder<HttpObject> {

    @Override
    protected Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpObject msg) throws Exception {
        // do some work, but leave msg unchanged
        BufUtil.retain(msg); // Why do I need to call BufUtil.retain(msg) ???
        return msg;
}
```

If I don't call BufUtil.retain on msg, it seems to get GCd and I get all sorts of spurious errors.

Answer (score 9):

`HttpContent` extends `ReferenceCounted` to keep track of the life cycle of the buffer it holds.  When a `ReferenceCounted` is instantiated, it starts its life with `refCnt` of `1`.  If you call `retain()` on it, `refCnt` is increased.  `refCnt` is decreased on `release()`, and the underlying resource (`ByteBuf` in this case) is destroyed once `refCnt` becomes `0`.

Usually, a handler does not need to keep a reference to the message it finished handling, because the message is usually thrown away or transformed into something else once handled.  Therefore, `release()` method must be called on the message once your handler is done with it.  This is often error-prone and will lead to resource leak very easily.

To avoid the leak that is very hard to track down, extend `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` which calls `release()` automatically on the messages once they are handled.

For more information about reference counting in Netty, please read [this wiki page](http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html).  It also gives you the detailed information about how to troubleshooting the buffer leaks by making use of Netty's buffer leak detection mechanism.

Comment: Hi, thanks. It makes sense in a setting where performance is of utmost importance. If only it could be made more evident...

Comment: @trustin - I was also confused and surprised by all of this reference counting bleeding out into the user API.  The API design should "do the least surprising thing" and "be as simple as possible".  Perhaps you could use a familiar Java construct instead:  a resource, as in try-with-resources.  Or just have the message Object behave like a user would expect by default and only get the highly performance optimized, but more complicated version via a separate interface; Performance isn't as important as quickly building an application with confidence it isn't leaking memory.

Comment: @Ryan, if there was an explicit way to specify the life cycle of an object in Java, such as destructors in C++, we would have never needed to introduce reference counting for most cases.  However, Java does not have such a thing, and thus reference counting is the most efficient way to manage buffers.  It's not pretty, but unfortunately, it was the only way to handle direct buffers safely. By the way, buffer leaks in Netty are relatively easy to find: http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html#wiki-h2-10

Comment: @trustin I am totally confused by your saying "*Usually, a handler does not have a reference to the message it processed*". Let's take a look at the method `public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)`, I think the `Object msg` is the message processed by the handler. And obviously, the handler `HAS` a reference to the message -- the `msg` argument. **Do you mean there's no member field of a handler that keep reference to a message?** And I am also wondering that Netty is just a framework built upon JVM, how could it overthrow the JVM GC mechanism?

Comment: @trustin and btw, I checked the Netty 4.0.25.Final. It seems `HttpObject` is just an interface and does not extend the `ReferenceCounted`.

Comment: @trustin According to the wiki page you posted: *"Since Netty version 4, the life cycle of certain objects are managed by their reference counts rather than the garbage collector. "* How could Netty overthrown the JVM GC mechanism? I have read a lot of threads saying that GC cannot be disabled.

Comment: @smwikipedia Updated the answer to make it clearer. Please read the 'troubleshooting buffer leaks' section. Reference counting is basically to implement pooling.

Comment: @smwikipedia Updated the wiki page: https://github.com/netty/netty/wiki/Reference-counted-objects (will take some time until the netty.io page is sync'd) Let me know if you think it can be improved.

Comment: @trustin Thanks for your replies. I read the wiki page. In the `Troubleshooting Buffer Leaks` section, it says "An object once garbage collected cannot be resurrected, and thus cannot be returned to the pool it came from ***or*** will produce ***memory leak***." I have 2 questions on this. (1) I guess it'll be more precise to change "*memory leak*" to "*pool leak*". Because the situation is pooled resource is drained unexpectedly, which is what `leak` means. (2) And I am not sure why we use "*or*" here. Does it mean synonymous?

Comment: @trustin And could you take a look at this thread? Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647048/why-do-we-need-to-manually-handle-reference-counting-for-netty-bytebuf-if-jvm-gc

Comment: @smwikipedia 'or' should be 'and thus' indeed. Thanks for a suggestion.

Comment: @smwikipedia for the thread you mentioned, I guess the chosen answer is great already.

Comment: @trustin  Thanks for your confirmation.