# Understanding how Netty memory-leak would happen if release is not called

Tags: memory-leaks, netty

I have read various StackOverFlow QAs and external links and blogs about memory leak in Netty, starting from [ReferenceCountedObjects](http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html) and [ManuallyHandlingReferenceCounting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647048/why-do-we-need-to-manually-handle-reference-counting-for-netty-bytebuf-if-jvm-gc), [BufferOwnership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781276/buffer-ownership-in-netty-4-how-is-buffer-life-cycle-managed), [TwitterBlog](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2013/netty-4-at-twitter-reduced-gc-overhead.html), [ChannelOutboundHandlerFlushedBufferLeak](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/netty/Ve4lnRvFXjM), and other links that stem from these pages.

I understand that if the application doesn't release the resource once it is done with it, the actual memory itself will be GCed, but still Netty's pool size will increase and cause memory leak.

Couple of quotes from the links above explaining this are "even if the buffers themselves are garbage collected, the internal data structures used to store the pool will not.", "PooledByteBufAllocator uses the Recycler as well for “pooling” the ByteBuf container (not the memory it refer to itself tho)."

Can someone please explain a bit more about how this could happen? If `ByteBuf` is a container which is referring to a memory, how can the memory be collected while the `ByteBuf` is still in Netty memory pool? I visualize that Netty maintains a pool of `ByteBuf`(s) and reuse the memory it refers to when its reference count becomes 0. With this assumption, I can't understand how the memory itself can be GCed if the `ByteBuf` is still present in Netty's pool?

Can someone please clarify it in simple terms?

Answer (score 5):

So let me try to clarify things here.... basically Netty uses separate pools for the memory itself and for the container around it.

The container is ByteBuf here. Netty is pooling the ByteBuf in a Recycler (which is basically an object pool). The important thing to note here is that it "nulls" out the reference to the actual underlying memory (aka storage) that will be used to actually store the bytes.

The bytes itself (that will be exposed via the ByteBuf container) exist in a different pool. This pool only holds the backing storage for the ByteBuf but not the ByteBuf itself. The backing storage may be on-heap (byte[]) or off-heap (native/direct memory).

So both of these can be be the cause of a memory leak in theory. While in practice most of the memory leaks are caused by not calling ByteBuf.release() which leaks the backing memory.

Comment: Norman, ByteBuf "nulls" out the actual underlying memory in the deallocate method, right? The deallocate method is called only when the ByteBuf is released completely and the refcnt becomes 0. Am I right? My main doubt is, how can the underlying memory be GCed when the ByteBuf is not released completely. I understand that the resource should be released. If it is not, both the actual memory and the ByteBuf container should not be GCed. The whole point of this question is to understand, 'how can the underlying memory be GCed when the ByteBuf is not released completely?'

Comment: Are you asking how we implemented the leak detector here ?

Comment: Norman, thanks a lot for following it up. I am not asking about the full internal implementation detail. But can you please be kind enough to explain conceptually? I mean, *how can the underlying memory which is referred by the ByteBuf container be GCed when the ByteBuf itself is not released completely? ByteBuf nulls the underlying memory's reference only when its refcnt reaches 0. Until the refcnt reaches 0, ByteBuf holds a reference to the underlying memory. So, how does the underlying memory gets GCed when the ByteBuf is not released completely*? Thanks in advance!